# ProGuard not working as expected after Android Studio update

Tags: android, android-proguard

Since I updated Android Studio to version `1.2.1.1` I have the following problem:

Whenever I build a release version / build variant of my app, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` on the [Adjust library](https://github.com/adjust/android_sdk) I have included in the project as a library module.

The stracktrace:

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.adjust.sdk.AdjustConfig
            at de.myapp.GlobalApp.prepareAdjust(GlobalApp.java:111)
            at de.myapp.GlobalApp.onCreate(GlobalApp.java:71)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Corresponding part of my code:

```
    AdjustConfig config = new AdjustConfig(this, someString, otherString);
```

When I turn off Proguard with     `minifyEnabled false;` in my `build.gradle`, the error is gone.

My proguard-rules.pro looks like this:

```
-keepattributes **
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,** {*;}
-dontpreverify
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink
-dontwarn **
```

These Proguard rules might look a bit strange because they do but one thing: obfuscate classes in the `android.support.v7.internal.view.menu` package. 
This procedure is a workaround for a [a known issue of the Android Support library on Samsung devices](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=248142).

Even more confusingly, the `NoClassDefFoundError` only occurs only devices running Android < `5.0`.

Any ideas on what the reason could be or how to fix this?

Comment: Any lead on what type `com.adjust.sdk.AdjustConfig` is? Interesting that `minifyEnabled` triggers the error...

Comment: @shkschneider Yes you can have a look here: https://github.com/adjust/android_sdk/blob/master/Adjust/adjust/src/main/java/com/adjust/sdk/AdjustConfig.java

Comment: Try this line instead of yours:


````-keepnames class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,android.support.v7.** {*;}
````
I think that line that you are using right now tells proguard to obfuscate EVERY class in the project except the ones which are starting with android.support, etc. This will take only specific package into an account

Comment: @scana I verified that no other classes of my project are being obfuscated. 
Your line actually leads to classes other than the support menu ones being obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

> If you are using Proguard, add these lines to your Proguard file:

```
-keep class com.adjust.sdk.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.** { *; }
```

Comment: I already tried explicitly adding this, made no difference. Which is logical because it is already implied in the keep statement from my post (mind the negating exclamation mark).